# Is the converse true too?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

LDMJ is a circle centered at O. Point K, on DJ, bisects chord LM. DSJ is another circle drawn using DJ as diameter. If $\alpha = 90^0$, then KS = KL.

This can be proved by applying “power of a point” couple of times.

Question:- Is the converse true? (i. e. If KS = KL, will $\alpha$ be $90^0$?)

Comment: Do we still have *LDMJ is a circle centered at O. Point K, on DJ, bisects chord LM. DSJ is another circle drawn using DJ as diameter*? If yes, it seems to be an obvious "yes".

Comment: Yes. We do. Would like to see your proof.

Answer (score 1):

The circle center $K$ radius $KL$ intersects the circle with diameter $DJ$ at two points $S_1$ and $S_2$, which are symmetry about $DJ$. By your argument (when $\alpha=90^\circ$), one of these $S_1$ and $S_2$ is $S$. It follows that $K$ is the middle point of $S_1S_2$ and we are done.

Comment: $SS_1$ is the common chord of the said circles but will it pass through K? In other words, are $S, K, S_1$ collinear ?

Comment: Yes, since $SS_1\perp DJ$ by symmetry and $K$ is the projection of $S$ onto $DJ$.

Comment: Is it possible to prove it in the (Euclidean) geometrical way rather than just saying K is the projection of S onto DJ?